Como realizar una consulta con un case que me muestre dos resultados en una misma fila?
¿Cómo mostrar dos resultados en el mismo case?
select (a.prvrtn)RTN, (b.CmpCabAplGtoPol)Documento, (b.cmpprvcai)CAI, 
(b.CmpPrvFactura)NFactura, (a.PrvNombre)Ndocumento, (b.CmpPrvFacFecha)Fechaemision,
(b.CmpFchCmp)Fechacontable, (b.CmpCabAplGtoPol)N_oce,
(case when c.CmpTaxTaza = 0 then SUM(c.CmpTotGastos2) ELSE 0 END) Excento,
(case when c.CmpTaxTaza = 15 then SUM(c.CmpTotGastos2) ELSE 0 END) Gravado15,
(case when c.CmpTaxTaza = 18 then SUM(c.CmpTotGastos2) ELSE 0 END) Gravado18
from PROVEEDORES a
inner join COMPRAS b on b.PrvID = a.PrvID
inner join COMP_DET c on c.CmpNumero = b.CmpNumero
where c.TndID='4' and CmpPrvFactura='004-034-01-00037165' and b.CmpFchCmp between '20240801' and '20240831'
group by a.PrvRTN, b.CmpCabAplGtoPol, b.cmpprvcai, b.CmpPrvFactura, a.PrvNombre, b.CmpPrvFacFecha, b.CmpFchCmp,
c.CmpTaxTaza
order by b.CmpPrvFacFecha asc

Ya que en mi código lo hice por separado para poder ver si funcionaba, pero hay registros que muestran que hay compras con productos sin puesto y con el 15% los resultados los muestra correctos.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! sql ejecuta fila a fila.. si vos queres que salgan en la misma fila, deberias o joinerla consigo mismo, o buscar otro metodo por el cual calcular ese valor en la fila en la que estas.. pero sin ver los detalles de la tabla es muy dificil ayudarte

Ahora que miro bien, porque haces un case que hace siempre lo mismo? si es para cambiar el nombre de la columna, mejor ponerlo en otra columna que diga el porcentaje aplicado ;)

De paso, porfa aclara para que base de datos es..

Buenas!, Esta bien, agradezco los consejos procurare aplicarlos para futuras consultas mi base de datos es en sql server.

No dejes para mañana lo que puedes hacer hoy :) Edita siempre en el momento para agregar más detalles. Recuerda que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros usuarios que lleguen a tener un problema similar más adelante.

Por cierto... La palabra no es excento, es exento.

Parece que el problema es que tienes la función de agregado en el lugar incorrecto. Lo que tienes que hacer es incluir toda la expresión CASE dentro de la función y eliminar la columna de la Tasa (no es taza, esas son para tomar) del GROUP BY.
Dejo el ejemplo de como quedaría después de darle un poco de formato a tu código y seguir buenas prácticas al usar alias de tablas.
SELECT  pr.prvrtn            AS RTN, 
        co.CmpCabAplGtoPol   AS Documento, 
        co.cmpprvcai         AS CAI, 
        co.CmpPrvFactura     AS NFactura, 
        pr.PrvNombre         AS Ndocumento, 
        co.CmpPrvFacFecha    AS Fechaemision,
        co.CmpFchCmp         AS Fechacontable, 
        co.CmpCabAplGtoPol   AS N_oce,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cd.CmpTaxTaza = 0  THEN cd.CmpTotGastos2 ELSE 0 END) AS Excento,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cd.CmpTaxTaza = 15 THEN cd.CmpTotGastos2 ELSE 0 END) AS Gravado15,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cd.CmpTaxTaza = 18 THEN cd.CmpTotGastos2 ELSE 0 END) AS Gravado18
FROM        PROVEEDORES AS pr
INNER JOIN  COMPRAS     AS co on co.PrvID = pr.PrvID
INNER JOIN  COMP_DET    AS cd on cd.CmpNumero = co.CmpNumero
WHERE cd.TndID         = '4' 
AND   co.CmpPrvFactura = '004-034-01-00037165' 
AND   co.CmpFchCmp     BETWEEN '20240801' AND '20240831'
GROUP BY pr.PrvRTN, 
         co.CmpCabAplGtoPol, 
         co.cmpprvcai, 
         co.CmpPrvFactura, 
         pr.PrvNombre, 
         co.CmpPrvFacFecha, 
         co.CmpFchCmp
ORDER BY co.CmpPrvFacFecha ASC;


Muchas gracias! me muestra todo en la misma fila, tomare en cuenta el aplicar los alias.
